# Error when parsing Google Directions API (Specified cast is not valid)

Tags: android, json, xamarin, google-maps-api-3

I am new with xamarin.
I want to parse with json a response from Google Directions Api.
I created a class for my object:

```
 public class GeocodedWaypoint
{
    public string geocoder_status { get; set; }
    public string place_id { get; set; }
    public List<string> types { get; set; }
}

public class Northeast
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Southwest
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Bounds
{
    public Northeast northeast { get; set; }
    public Southwest southwest { get; set; }
}

public class Distance
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class Duration
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class EndLocation
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class StartLocation
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Distance2
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class Duration2
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class EndLocation2
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Polyline
{
    public string points { get; set; }
}

public class StartLocation2
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Step
{
    public Distance2 distance { get; set; }
    public Duration2 duration { get; set; }
    public EndLocation2 end_location { get; set; }
    public string html_instructions { get; set; }
    public Polyline polyline { get; set; }
    public StartLocation2 start_location { get; set; }
    public string travel_mode { get; set; }
    public string maneuver { get; set; }
}

public class Leg
{
    public Distance distance { get; set; }
    public Duration duration { get; set; }
    public string end_address { get; set; }
    public EndLocation end_location { get; set; }
    public string start_address { get; set; }
    public StartLocation start_location { get; set; }
    public List<Step> steps { get; set; }
    public List<object> traffic_speed_entry { get; set; }
    public List<object> via_waypoint { get; set; }
}

public class OverviewPolyline
{
    public string points { get; set; }
}

public class Route
{
    public Bounds bounds { get; set; }
    public string copyrights { get; set; }
    public List<Leg> legs { get; set; }
    public OverviewPolyline overview_polyline { get; set; }
    public string summary { get; set; }
    public List<object> warnings { get; set; }
    public List<object> waypoint_order { get; set; }
}

public class DirectionsDto
{
    public List<GeocodedWaypoint> geocoded_waypoints { get; set; }
    public List<Route> routes { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

And I tried to deserialize the response like this:

```
JsonValue json = await FetchDataAsync(url);
        DirectionsDto directions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DirectionsDto>(json);

        private async Task<String> FetchDataAsyncXML(string url)
    {
        // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        request.Method = "GET";

        // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:
        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // Use this stream to build a JSON document object:

                return response.GetResponseStream().ToString();

            }
        }
    }
```

I get this error: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
I need only one thing from the entire response.
I need only OverviewPolyline. It is at the end of the response.
If it is easier with xml then I think is ok to use xml also.

I am stuck here and is very frustrating.

Comment: Have you tried Json.NET?

Comment: I am using Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: An example for the api call is this https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=44.439663,26.096306&destination=44.8564798,24.8691824

Comment: Will be nice to see the stack trace. Try validating your model using https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: I have tried your code. Could you please show your `FetchDataAsync((url))` method? There is only      `FetchDataAsyncXML(string url)` method and it is not called in your code,  and there is no `JsonValue` class. About `InvalidCastException`, I suggest you check the respond from the url. Please edit your post, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Change `JsonValue` to `string`, because the type of the return value in `FetchDataAsyncXML` is `string`:

```
        string json = await FetchDataAsyncXML("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=44.439663,26.096306&destination=44.8564798,24.8691824");
        Android.Util.Log.Error("lv", json);
        DirectionsDto directions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DirectionsDto>(json);
        Android.Util.Log.Error("lv=========", directions.status);
```

and in `FetchDataAsyncXML` method do like this:

```
private async Task<String> FetchDataAsyncXML(string url)
{
    // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
    request.ContentType = "application/xml";
    request.Method = "GET";

    // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:
    using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
    {
        // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            // Use this stream to build a JSON document object:

            //return response.GetResponseStream().ToString();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            //retrun html code 
            string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
            Android.Util.Log.Error("lv++", content);
            return content;

        }
    }
}
```